# Rails 7: Many-to-many self referencing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I have a table of actors and a table of movies. I want to add a possibility to find out the answer to the question "what other actors has a particular actor starred with and in what movies". Example: "Mark Hamill has starred with Harrison Ford in Star Wars".

I am creating and "actor_partners" table to act as the join table, which stores:

- actor1 ID
- actor2 ID
- movie ID

However I am struggling with this - as Mark Hamill's id could be either actor1 or actor2. In addition, using the below schema and model doesn't work: It gives the following error:

```
An error occurred when inspecting the object: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'actor_partners.actor_id' in 'where clause'>
  Actor Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `actors`.* FROM `actors` INNER JOIN `actor_partners` ON `actors`.`id` = `actor_partners`.`actor1_id` WHERE `actor_partners`.`actor_id` = 3 /* loading for inspect */ LIMIT 11
```

schema.db

```
# ... lots of other stuff
  create_table "actor_partners", charset: "utf8mb4", collation: "utf8mb4_general_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "actor1_id", null: false
    t.bigint "actor2_id", null: false
    t.string "movie_type", null: false
    t.bigint "movie_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["actor1_id", "actor2_id", "movie_id"], name: "index_actor_partners_on_actor1_id_and_actor2_id_and_movie_id", unique: true
    t.index ["actor1_id"], name: "index_actor_partners_on_actor1_id"
    t.index ["actor2_id"], name: "index_actor_partners_on_actor2_id"
    t.index ["movie_id"], name: "index_actor_partners_on_movie_id"
  end
  add_foreign_key "actor_partners", "actors", column: "actor1_id"
  add_foreign_key "actor_partners", "actors", column: "actor2_id"
  add_foreign_key "actor_partners", "movies"
```

actor_partner.rb

```
class ActorPartner < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :actor1, class_name: 'Actor'
  belongs_to :actor2, class_name: 'Actor'
  belongs_to :movie
  validates :movie_type, presence: true
end
```

actor.rb

```
class Actor < ApplicationRecord
  # ... lots of other relationsships and stuff
  has_many :actor_partners, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :a_partners, through: :actor_partners, source: :actor1
  has_many :b_partners, through: :actor_partners, source: :actor2
end
```

Comment: this is a very heavy way to go, especially for your intended use. You are duplicating a lot of data. I'd kill the actor_partners. Just have an actor_movies table. Then you can query to see which movie has both actors, or three actors, etc.

Comment: I thought of that but I will want to have a tab on every actor‘s „show“ page that lists other actors and movies they appear in together. Querying all movies, and all actors, and then summarize the same actors (Harrison Ford: in Star wars,  Empire Strikes back etc) seems way heavier?

Comment: As you have, or will find out, that's a going to be a have ask in any case, 50+ actors per movie * X movies. Mark Hamill has 300+ acting credits. That's 15,000 + rows just for Mark Hamill. If you want to run down this road -- only query the primary actor and have rows for each partner. This means for the Mark Hamill Harrison Ford combo, you will have two records for Star Wars, one for with each as the primary actor.

Comment: "Querying all movies, and all actors" that's what cache is for. New movies don't come out every 5 minutes, it can be a veeery long lived cache. To a point of generating static html into memcache or redis.

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions. I think I will go with @dbugger 's comment and create inverse records. This is my "private collection" database (where I store movies that I own on blueray), so it isn't like going super crazy with 300+ credits for Mark Hamill :)

Answer (score 1):

No matter how you do this it's going to be a very heavy lift to do at read time, but this is all static data once written. I think it would be a much better idea to pre-cache this data at write time in the `actors` table so your reads are simple/quick. I'm assuming that you write a movie and all its actors at the same time.

Very easy to have a JSONB field in your `actors` table that stores an hash of "costars", where the other actor's `id` is the key (to avoid duplicates), and just update that when you write a new movie into your DB.

Obviously you'll need a backfill to process that now, but even that won't be too hard because you can easily just loop through your `movies` table in batches.

Comment: thanks. that is a good idea. I will continue to investigate